# Efficient way of scaling column based on value in other column in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, scale

I want to scale values in the column of a `dataframe` based on values in another colum. For example, here is a simple example

```
d<-data.frame(x=runif(5,0,10),y=sample(c(1,2),size=5,replace=TRUE))
```

gives the output:

```
         x  y
1 1.0895865 2
2 0.8261554 2
3 5.3503761 2
4 3.3940759 1
5 6.2786637 1
```

I want to scale the x values based on the y values, so what I want is to have:

```
(x|y=1 - average(x's | y=1))/std.dev(x's|y=1)
```

then replace the x values in d with the scaled values, similarly for the `x` values with `y=2`.

What I have done so far is a bit clunky:

```
     d1<-subset(d,y==1)
d2<-subset(d,y==2)

d1$x<-(d1$x-mean(d1$x))/sd(d1$x)
d2$x<-(d2$x-mean(d2$x))/sd(d2$x)
```

and then binding all the results in one big data frame, but this is a bit tedious since my actual data has 50 different values for y and I'd like to do this for multiple (different) columns.

Comment: Please add `set.seed()` to your code to make it reproducible and share the expected output.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `ave(d$x,d$y,FUN=function(x) (x-mean(x))/sd(x))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this using `group_by` and `mutate` from the `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)
d %>% 
  group_by(y) %>% 
  mutate(x = (x - mean(x)) / sd(x))
```

Comment: could you explain the '%>%' why is the format so different to a normal function?? this works great btw!

Comment: `%>%` is the chaining operator from `magrittr`. It makes it easier and more readable when chaining together several functions. If you write the above code without `%>%`, it becomes `mutate(group_by(d, y), x = (x - mean(x)) / sd(x))`. Basically instead of writing `f(x, y)` you can write `x %>% f(y)`. Also check [here](https://github.com/smbache/magrittr) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

This task is usually performy by `group by` in `dplyr` and using `scale`

```
 library(dplyr)
 d %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(x2=scale(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(d)`), grouped by 'b', assign (`:=`) the `scale` of 'x' to 'x2'.

```
 setDT(d)[, x2 := scale(x) , by = y]
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11857424)

Comment: @AlessandroCuttin  Added the description.